# Tablet Server Access for Accumulo Running on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloudera-cdh, accumulo

I am attempting to run a simple driver to write some data to an Accumulo 1.5 instance running on AWS that is using a single node cluster managed by CDH 4.7 .  The client successfully connects to zookeeper but then fails with the following message:

```
2015-06-26 12:12:13 WARN  ServerClient:163 - Failed to find an available server in the list of servers: [172.31.13.210:10011:9997 (120000)]
```

I tried applying the solution listed
[here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ACCUMULO-687)
, but this has not resolved the issue.  The IP that is set for the master/slave is the internal AWS IP for the server.

Other than the warning message, I have not been able to find anything else in the Accumulo logs that indicate what is preventing connection to the master server.  Any suggestions on where to look next?

--EDIT--
It looks like zookeeper is returning connectors to the remote client that contain references to the internal IP of the AWS server. The remote client cannot use these connectors because it does not know about the internal IP. When I changed the internal IPs in the thrift connector objects to the public IP, the connection works fine. In essence I can't figure out how to get zookeeper to return public IPs and not AWS internal ones for remote clients

Answer (score 0):

> 172.31.13.210:10011:9997

This looks really strange. This should be an IP/hostname and a port. It looks like you have two ports somehow..

Did you list ports in the `slaves` file in ACCUMULO_CONF_DIR? This file should only contain the hostname/IP. If you want to change the port that a TabletServer listens on, you need to change tserver.port.client.

Comment: I changed the port that the TabletServer is listening to to 10011 to avoid conflicts with cdh services.  The slaves file is listing the internal dns of the aws server without ports.

Comment: If the ACCUMUL_CONF_DIR was incorrect when accumulo init was called would that potentially cause this issue?

Comment: It shouldn't. `accumulo init` initializes HDFS and zookeeper, doesn't affect the processes. You set tserver.port.client to 10011 in accumulo-site.xml? That's it?

Comment: master.port.client is set to to port 10010.  At this point, I believe Accumulo is configured correctly and that the problem is with my AWS instance somehow.